# Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When building a Jenkins pipeline job (Jenkins ver. 2.7.4), I get this warning:

```
Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated
```

How do I fix it?

Pipeline script snippet:

```
stage 'Workspace Cleanup'
deleteDir()
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

From Jenkins pipeline stage step [doc](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-stage-step/#pipeline-stage-step):

> An older, deprecated mode of this step did not take a block
> argument...

In order to remove the warning just add a block argument:

```
stage('Stage Name') {
   // some block
}
```

You can also generate a stage step using [Snippet Generator](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator).

Comment: yeah, but that messes up the workflow, since block argument makes the step automatically parallel

Comment: `stage 'Stage Name' { ... }` is not enough?

Comment: @Roland Tepp Are you sure this is true? I have multiple stages with braces and they are run sequentially although there is another free slave.

Comment: @Knitschi no, I am not. But when I first tried it, this was the apparent result.

Comment: @PawełPrażak didn't seem enough, I get an error without the `()`

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano it's the curly brackets `{}` that are important.

Comment: @Archimedes Trajano I needed to add an empty string `stage('')` to get it work. Also note that the name of the stage needs to be unique amongst its siblings.

Answer (score 0):

An older, **deprecated mode of this step did not take a block argument**, and accepted a concurrency parameter

So i'd guess in your pipeline blocks doesn't have that `stage`. 
Just put the stage block like :

```
stage "stage name" {
   // some block
}
```

or just

```
stage "stage name"
//some block
```